# Stuck on this High School Coding Activity

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm stuck on one activity (although this is a mini activity, I need to finish five a day). This is only saving the one's digit and removing everything else.

**This is the instruction:**

2. The "Necklace Problem". The necklace problem begins with two single digit numbers. The
   next number is obtained by adding the first two numbers together and saving only the ones-digit. This process is repeated until the "necklace" closes by returning to the original two
   numbers. For example, if the starting numbers are 1 and 8, twelve steps are required to close
   the "necklace".
   EXAMPLE 1, 8 -> 1 8 9 7 6 3 9 2 1 3 4 7 1 8 <- 14 Steps
   Your program will show the starting number, the ending number, the amount of steps, and the
   entire "necklace".

**And this is my code for now:**

```
start_number = input('Start number: ')
end_number = input('Ending number: ')

def necklace (start_number, end_number):
    while start_number != end_number
        start_number = start_number + end_number
        i += 1
        if start_number == end_number:
            break
        
print start_number
print end_number
print i
```

Comment: OK, and what is wrong with your current code? Have you tried to include anything from the essential part of the problem (adding and keeping the last digit) into your code? Looking at it, it would give the impression that you haven't tried anything of the sort, and you want us to do the essential work. Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, and you're welcome to edit your question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `input()` with an `int()`, otherwise `input` returns a string value.

Comment: So basically I don't want the answer to the code as the answer to this question, guys. I just want to know how I can only save the one's digit and remove everything else. Since I couldn't get that to work, I was having a hard time on checking other parts of my code.

Comment: Hint: when you get an input of number i.e type `int`, you need to convert that to a `string` type to be able to apply the slice method to get the ones position. Once you have that portion, you should be able to iterate over the index and when `start_number == final_number` break and print.

Comment: OK, then your question should be explicitely and only about that. What have you tried? What got wrong? You could try to create a minimal program first: just input two numbers, add them, try to extract the last digit. You'll certainly notice some important things along the way. To extract the last digit, how would you do if the number is represented as an integer, or as a string? What would be the most convenient? Go on! ;)

Comment: @JustinKim the modulo operator `%` gives you the remainder (rather than the quotient) of a division problem. Can you find the right modulo to keep just the ones digit?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille
Right. I tried slicing it, dividing it, changing it to a string, and etc., but I couldn't figure it out at last and asked this question. I really intended to get help only on the part where I can only keep the one's digit, but I pretty much agree that my question didn't specifically ask on the part; it looked like I was trying to get the answer right away. Thanks for the advice anyways! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes that turned out to be the way to keep the one's digit. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @pavel Oh I missed that, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @FishingCode Thanks, I'll keep that it my notes. Thank you! :)

Comment: I just rolled back your last edit. I really appreciate your efforts and feedback, so please don't take it negatively. It's just the way SO works: we don't edit questions to mark them as solved, say thanks or whatever.The usual way to say thanks is to accept the answer you found the more useful, and/or upvote the really useful ones (and only the really useful ones, that's what keeps the rating meaningful). So, anyway, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this one step at a time. It sounds like we want a function that, given the two initial inputs, produces the list that describes the necklace including the final two outputs.

```py
from typing import List

def make_necklace(a: int, b: int) -> List[int]:
    necklace = [a, b]
```

It's pretty easy to derive the next number:

```py
    # we don't really know when we'll leave the loop, so loop forever and handle it later
    while True:
        # add the last two elements and modulo by 10 to keep only the 1s digit
        next_link = (necklace[-1] + necklace[-2]) % 10
        necklace.append(next_link)
```

but it's harder to figure out when to stop. What's the stop condition again? When the last two elements are the same as the first two elements? Wait: we can compare list elements, right? Let's do that.

```py
        if necklace[0:2] == necklace[-2:]:
            break  # leave the infinite loop
```

Then once we're out, we just return the necklace.

```py
    return necklace
```

Calling this function now gives you the whole chain of the necklace, from which you should easily be able to display the rest of the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question without giving away the entire problem:

You can get the ones-digit of a number by performing a modulo 10 operation. For example:
52 % 10 = 2

This would work for any number of digits, so 5842068 % 10 would equal 8.

More information on modulo [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/)

Comment: Thank you so much for that! It was really tough to come up with a way to find the one's digit.. Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
first_number = int(input('First single digit number: '))
second_number = int(input('Second single digit number: '))

def necklace (first_num, second_num):
  neck_list = [first_num,second_num]
  neck_list.append(int((neck_list[-1]+neck_list[-2])%10))
  while neck_list[:2] !=neck_list[-2:]:
    neck_list.append(int((neck_list[-1]+neck_list[-2])%10))
  return neck_list
neck_list = necklace(first_number,second_number)
print("first number: {}".format(neck_list[0]),"second number: {}".format(neck_list[1]),"necklace size: {}".format(len(neck_list)),"necklace: {}".format(neck_list),sep='\n')
```

**output:**
First single digit number: 1
Second single digit number: 8
first number: 1
second number: 8
necklace size: 14
necklace: [1, 8, 9, 7, 6, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 1, 8]

**The code is self-explanatory.**

Comment: Right, for me figuring out the %10 part was really tough. Thanks a lot for the help!! :)